# copying a serialized file from one folder to other folder in every 2 minutes

Tags: java

Please do not consider this question as repeated one ,I have few files in a folder ter , that is ter folder is in c : drive and it contain a seriliazed file named gfr.ser so the complete path is (C:\ter\gfr.ser) , Now i want this gfr.ser file to be copied in another folder inside C: itself named bvg so I want file to copied to path (C:\bvg\gfr.ser) below is the java class , please advise can I achieve the same ,please advise

```
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;


// Create a class extends with TimerTask
public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {

    // Add your task here
    public void run() {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start c:\\ter\\gfr.ser");
    }
}

//Main class
public class SchedulerMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        Timer time = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object
        ScheduledTask st = new ScheduledTask(); // Instantiate SheduledTask class
        time.schedule(task, now ,TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));

    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html may interest you. Also [`FileUtils.copyFile()`](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-copy-file-in-java-program.html) is nice alternative to standard Java libraries.

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks a lot could you also please advise how to fit the second option in my above program

Answer (score 0):

I would say that easier option for you is probably first option from my link in comment (you wouldn't have to download additional libraries to your project). Here is simple code that you can use in your application

```
Path source = new File("C:\\ter\\gfr.ser").toPath();
Path target = new File("C:\\bvg\\gfr.ser").toPath();
Files.copy(source, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

But make sure that `C:\bvg` folder exists before you start copping.

---

Since you are using JDK 1.6 [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-copy-file-in-java/) example is better. I assume that you are trying to replace old file with new one. Here is how you can do it:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;

        try {
            File targetDirectory = new File("C:\\bvg");
            if (!targetDirectory.exists()) targetDirectory.mkdirs();

            File source = new File("C:\\ter\\gfr.ser");
            File target = new File("C:\\bvg\\gfr.ser");

            inStream = new FileInputStream(source);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(target);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;
            // copy the file content in bytes
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();

            System.out.println("File is copied successful!");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// Main class
public class SchedulerMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        Timer time = new Timer();
        ScheduledTask task = new ScheduledTask();

        time.schedule(task, new Date(), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(2));

    }
}
```

Comment: I agree to that But I want to put this inside the scheduler example of above one , please advise

Comment: Put my code inside `run()` method in your `ScheduledTask` class. You may also need to import `java.nio.file.*;` and `java.io.File;`.

Comment: That explains a lot. Is it big problem to upgrade to 1.7?

Comment: I was looking for jdk 1.6.

Comment: OK. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-copy-file-in-java/) you have simple example of coping files with older version of JDK.

Comment: but how I would fit this example in my run() method of above program please advise

Comment: Check my edit, in Java7 it would be lot shorter... but it is your choice. If it solves your problem you can accept it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort but one thing is that my target folder is empty it does not contain any file I just need to copy the file from source to target, so I am not replacing ,my folder bvg is empty, I need to check bvg folder in every 2 minutes and if file is not there then I need to put this file rite now when I executed the above program it throws an error since bvg folder was not having the file initially

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. When I remove `gfr.ser` from `bvg` folder and run this code it just copy it to it, then after two minutes it copy it again (replacing it).

Comment: @user2035385 Could you show what error you got when you executed this code?

Comment: When I am executing the above program at starting there is no file in bvg folder.

Comment: @user2035385 Could you be more specific? I'm not sure what you mean by `When I am executing the above program at starting there is no file in bvg folder.`. There is no file before or after you execute my code? If before then it shouldn't be problem since `bvg` is **target folder** (not source) so who cares that there was no file there before. If after then you should get some exception while executing program (if so info from that exception could be helpful). Or maybe it finished with `"File is copied successful!"` massage but wile wasn't copied (did you refresh folder to confirm it)?